# Markov chains - state classification and calculating periods of each state

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain $X$ on state space $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with transition matrix as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\\frac{1}{4}&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Suppose $X_0=2$

I have the following questions I want to solve:

(1) Determining which states are essential and which are transient.

(2) Calculating the period of each state.

(3) Finding the mean time taken for $X$ to visit the set of states $\{1,4\}$

This is what I've done so far:
(1) $\{4\}$ is absorbing so is in its own communicating class. The other communicating class is $\{1,2,3\}$. Since $\{4\}$ is absorbing, it is essential. $\{1,2,3\}$ are inessential - for example we could go $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 4$ and then never return to $1$. Thus $\{1,2,3\}$ is transient.

(2) The period of a state is equal to $\gcd\{n>0:p_{ii}^{(n)}>0\}$. Hence ${1}$ has period $2$ clearly; we need to take an even number of steps to return to $2$. Moreover, periodicity is a class property so $\{1,2,3\}$ all have period $2$. $\{4\}$ is aperiodic as it is absorbing - it has period $1$.

(3) This is the main one I'm not sure about. It is clear we want to use the first step decomposition for expectations - let $E_n$ denote the expected time taken to reach state $n$. Then $E_n=1+\sum_{j\in S}p_{kj}E_j$ where $S$ is the state space. What I don't quite get from the question is whether we are finding the mean time to reach one of $\{1\}$ or $\{4\}$. If this is the case, how would we do this?

Comment: Part 3 depends on where we start.  If we start in 1 or 4 the answer is 0.  Assuming we start in 2, make states 1 and 4 into one combined state.

Comment: @Michael yep just edited - we start in $X_0=2$- thanks for pointing this out! By making them a combined state what do you mean?

Comment: We treat the two states 1 and 4 as a single state (1,4).

Comment: Your formula for $E_n$ is incorrect. The left hand side depends on $n$ while the right hand side depends on $k$.  Also, $E_n$ should be interpreted as the expected time to reach a certain destination given we **start** in state $n$, which is not how you described it.

Comment: @Michael ah I'm confused:( how do we do it?

Comment: For this problem, $E_n$ is the expected time to reach 1 or 4, given we start in state $n$.  So clearly $E_1=E_4=0$ and you only need to solve for $E_2, E_3$ by writing equations for them in terms of themselves.  You will get two linear equations with two unknowns $E_2$ and $E_3$.  The idea is that as we are traversing the Markov chain in pursuit of our destination, and we happen to land on state 3, the expected remaining time is $E_3$ regardless of the past.